# Describe the automorphism group of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, automorphism-group

a)Describe the automorphism group of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z})$.

b) Prove that if a Group G has the trivial center then $|\operatorname{Aut}(G)| \geq |G|$.

My attempt:
a) Clearly, $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ is a cyclic group.

We know that the automorphism group of the cyclic group of order n is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z})^{*}$, and an abelian group of order $\phi(n)$.

This implies $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z})^{*}$.

Let $G=(\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ and $|G|=\phi(9)=6$. By classification of order of 6 group, we have $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ because $G$ is abelian and hence it is cyclic.

b)We know that $\operatorname{Inn}(G) \simeq G/Z(G)$, where $Z(G)$ denote the center of G.

Since $Z(G)=\{e\}$, then $\operatorname{Inn}(G) \simeq G$, and we know that $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$ is a normal subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

This implies $|\operatorname{Inn}(G)| \leq |\operatorname{Aut}(G)|$, i.e, $|G| \leq |\operatorname{Aut}(G)|$.

Is both part of the question correct? This is first time for me to study this topic. Please suggest me any improvement in this solution. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. Having multiple questions in the same post is discouraged and such posts may be closed, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464).

Answer (score 1):

Both answers are correct. Well done!

The intuition behind $(b)$ is that your group is maximally unabelian so conjugation gives for every choice of element a new inner automorphism.